# C++ destruction list

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a class to do a computation using some callbacks. those callbacks need to allocate data (dynamic arrays) that needs to live outside of the callback scope but not after the class destructs. I thought about make a `vector` of `auto_ptr` that will just get destructed automatically when the class destructs:

```
class MyClass
{
    vector<auto_ptr<MyObject>> ThingsToDie;
};
```

The problem is I have a lot of objects allocated and they don't share a base type so I can't use one `vector` for this, and making a vector for every type is a lot of work.
A hierarchy like the following:

```
auto_ptr_base (virtual destructor)
      |
 auto_ptr<T>
```

Will solve my problem because I could do something like

```
class MyClass
{
    vector<auto_ptr_base> ThingsToDie;
};
```

and the destruction will be virtually dispatched to each specialized type automatically.
The problem is that the STL doesn't have that hierarchy and I don't want to re-implement auto_ptr.
Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: If you have so many objects that need to be destroyed, I'd suspect your design could be better.

Comment: @JohnDibling: My design is a wrapper to a very stupid C interface, I can't make it better even if I want to (no source code of the C interface even if I felt crazy).

Comment: Avoid being in charge of everything.  Use the Observer pattern.

Comment: @Hans Passant: How will observer pattern help?

Comment: I thought you couldn't have a `vector` of `auto_ptr`s to begin with...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `vector<shared_ptr<void>>`.

Read this: **[Why do std::shared_ptr<void> work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913396/why-do-stdshared-ptrvoid-work)**

Comment: Do you know if that holds for shared_array?

Comment: +1 Besides, @Dani: take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/111478/198011

Comment: @Dani: lol, was looking for a way to get those <> there. missed the ; after &lt...