# Casting shared_ptr<T> to shared_ptr<void>

Tags: c++, casting, c++11, shared-ptr

I have a structure:

```
struct Params {
   std::shared_ptr<void> user_data;
   /* ... */
};
```

I want to use it like this:

```
int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<SpecializedParams> sp(new SpecializedParams(100));
  Params params;
  /* ... */
  params.user_data = std::static_pointer_cast<void>(sp); 
  /* ... */
  std::shared_ptr<SpecializedParams> sp2 = 
    std::static_pointer_cast<SpecializedParams>(
      params.user_data
    );
  /* ... */
  return 0;
}
```

Is this valid and safe?

Comment: What is params in main block ?

Comment: You can't `delete` a void pointer, so your code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @KerrekSB shared pointers to void are certainly valid. See here for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913396/why-do-stdshared-ptrvoid-work

Comment: @MichaelAnderson: Oh OK, the deleter is deduced from the argument, not from the pointee type - interesting!

Comment: You might want to use `static_pointer_cast` without `std::`. It will still work due to argument-dependent lookup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code, that actual deletes the shared object is determined when the shared pointer is created (that's why you need a complete type, when constructing the shared_ptr and not, when destructing the shared_ptr). Thus even when your shared_ptr is the last pointer that points to your SpecializedParams object, the object will get correctly destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

This should be safe as the void casted item is a shared_ptr too. It will add a reference to the existing element and it will not be released until the void casted item goes away.

Comment: The reason it works is because of the hidden deleter function stored with the `shared_ptr<T>` object ... Otherwise simply calling `delete` on a `void` pointer will not correctly deallocate the memory resources of the object being managed by the `shared_ptr<T>`.