# Managing C++ Delegate lifetime

Tags: c++, templates, delegates, variadic

I came across the following blog post which explains how to build C++ delegates using variadic templates: http://blog.coldflake.com/posts/2014-01-12-C++-delegates-on-steroids.html

I'm reproducing the Delegate class in the post here:

```
template<typename return_type, typename... params>
class Delegate
{
    typedef return_type (*Type)(void* callee, params...);
public:
    Delegate(void* callee, Type function)
         : fpCallee(callee)
         , fpCallbackFunction(function) {}

template <class T, return_type (T::*TMethod)(params...)>
static Delegate from_function(T* callee)
{
    Delegate d(callee, &methodCaller<T, TMethod>);
    return d;
}

return_type operator()(params... xs) const
{
    return (*fpCallbackFunction)(fpCallee, xs...);
}

private:

    void* fpCallee;
    Type fpCallbackFunction;

    template <class T, return_type (T::*TMethod)(params...)>
    static return_type methodCaller(void* callee, params... xs)
    {
        T* p = static_cast<T*>(callee);
        return (p->*TMethod)(xs...);
    }
};
```

And an example of how to use the class is given here:

```
class A
{
public:
    int foo(int x)
    {
        return x*x;
    }
    int bar(int x, int y, char a)
    {
        return x*y;
    }
};
int main()
{
    A a;
    auto d = Delegate<int, int>::from_function<A, &A::foo>(&a);
    auto d2 = Delegate<int, int, int, char>::from_function<A, &A::bar>(&a);
    printf("delegate with return value: d(42)=%d\n", d(42));
    printf("for d2: d2(42, 2, 'a')=%d\n", d2(42, 2, 'a'));
    return 0;
}
```

The technique is pretty cool, except that I would also like to have the Delegate class manage the callee's lifetime (in other words I would like to instantiate A on the heap and when the Delegate instance is deleted or goes out of scope, it should also be able to delete the callee (the A instance in this case)). Is there a simple way of doing this? Am I missing something? One solution would be to also pass a deleter object, which would cast the void* fpCallee to the correct type and then call delete ont it. Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: You could keep `shared_ptr<void>` instead of `void*` if you don't mind requiring every callee to be stored that way.

Comment: You could look at using shared pointers.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but a lambda that captures a `shared_ptr` to the callee and calls the function seems like it would do everything `Delegate` does with less fuss: `auto a = std::make_shared<A>(); auto d = [a](int x) { a->foo(x); };`

Comment: Not sure shared_ptr<void> is correct. Will it not call delete on void*, which is not good...

Comment: @BigLudinski the deleter will still know the actual type and do the right thing (as long as it was created as `std::shared_ptr<A>` and only cast to `std::shared_ptr<void>` later).

Comment: @BigLudinski it should work fine. There is an explanation here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913396/why-do-stdshared-ptrvoid-work

Comment: @Kindread & dlf  Thanks for the hint. I discovered something new about shared pointers :) OK so I guess this pretty much solves my problem :)

Comment: @BigLudinski Great; I'll rewrite as an answer for the record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `shared_ptr<void>` to store the callee instead of `void*` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913396/why-do-stdshared-ptrvoid-work) for why this doesn't cause delete problems; thanks Kindread). This would require you to keep every callee in a `shared_ptr`, but if you don't mind that, it would solve your problem.

And while this isn't an answer to the question, you could accomplish pretty much the same thing using a lambda instead of `Delegate`:

```
auto a = std::make_shared<A>();
auto d = [a](int x) { a->foo(x); };
```