# How to call the destructor of child class with a smart pointer of parent type?

Tags: c++, c++11

In my application I used to have a `unique_ptr<parent> _member` as a member of a custom class. The code worked fine. However when I recently tried to create another class that inherit from the `parent` class, and initialize `_member` using `_member = unique_ptr<child>(new child())` in the constructor, I realize that when the custom class got destroyed, the destructor of `_member` only calls the parent destructor but now the child destructor.

This behavior makes sense to me. Because afterall `_member` is of type `unique_ptr<parent>`. However I'm wondering what are the options for me to call the child destructor given only `_member`.

Comment: Have a `virtual` destructor for `parent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior does not make sense. If child's destructor needs to free memory, and it is not called, you will leak memory.

Parent needs to have a virtual destructor, to allow the destructors of derived classes to be called, when deleting them through a pointer to the parent.

Rule of thumb: If base class has at least one virtual function, it should have a virtual destructor.

Comment: +1, although the rule I follow is a bit more involved: if there is a virtual function, the type should have either a public virtual destructor or a protected non-virtual destructor. Both solve the same issue: code deleting through a pointer to base.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas That's a good rule!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Neil's fine answer, there's another route you could take.

If you were to use a `std::shared_ptr` instead of a `std::unique_ptr` you would gain the benefits of `std::shared_ptr`'s type erasure features. Let's look at an example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct X {
    ~X() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }
};

struct Y : X {
    ~Y() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<X> obj = std::make_shared<Y>();
}
```

This code, when run will output:

```
Y::~Y()
X::~X()
```

Comment: shared_ptr doesn't need virtual destructor? I didn't know that

Comment: @NeilKirk: That's correct. You can see this for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913396/why-do-stdshared-ptrvoid-work.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the parent class destructor virtual. On the off chance you have a use case that requires a class with no virtual functions to be destroyed properly and you don't want to use `std::shared_ptr` for its type-erased destruction feature, you can achieve the same thing with `unique_ptr` and a custom deleter:

```
template <typename T>
void delete_function(void* ptr) {
    // Tell GCC that we know we're doing something stupid and
    // it need not warn us about it.
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor"
    delete static_cast<T*>(ptr);
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
}

template <typename T>
using erased_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, void(*)(void*)>;

template <typename T, typename... Args>
inline erased_unique_ptr<T>
make_unique_erased(Args&&... args) {
    return erased_unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...), &delete_function<T>);
}
```

[See it live at Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/197c8114fd0001e9)